# Selective command-history in the terminal?

Tags: command-line

Within a terminal, when you press up in your keyboard, you get to see the past commands you have given to it before in order. I was wondering if there was a way to see only the commands in the past starting with -for instance, "ls -l". That way, if the list of commands is:

1. ls -l -a
2. cmake
3. cd ~/Desktop
4. cmake

A way to just write "ls" and tab or whatever combination of key-strokes needed to pop up the past command giving in to the terminal starting with "ls"

Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It won't show things only starting with `ls`, but you can do `Ctrl-R ls` to do a backwards search through history.  Repeat `Ctrl-R` to find the next match.

Comment: Thank you for the `CTRL+R` shortcut command.

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes it's useful to have this...

**Example**

Connecting to another machine using ssh:

start typing

```
ssh
```

Use <kbd>PgUp</kbd> key and your ssh ends up with your last used ... press <kbd>PgUp</kbd> again and it gives you the next one and so on. Like it?

You can use this:

Edit your .bashrc (`vi /home/<yourfolder>/.bashrc`) and add this:

```
$if Bash
    # Search history back and forward using page-up and page-down
    "\e[5~": history-search-backward
    "\e[6~": history-search-forward

    # Completion
    set match-hidden-files off
    set page-completions off
    set completion-query-items 350
    set show-all-if-ambiguous on

$endif
```

This adds only to your user's terminal this function. You will have to edit also the one of the root to have the same: you can follow [this tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Spec/EnhancedBash) from the wiki there's no way you can do it wrong, also there is a lot of extra stuff to improve your terminal experience...

Comment: You can even bind it to the Up/Down arrow keys: `bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'; bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'`, making it even more intuitive.

Answer (score 5):

To see the command history, use can use:

```
$ history
```

If you only want to see the past command begin with for example "ls", in my opinion I uses:

```
$ history | grep ls
```

Certainly the output will contain something not a command but contain "ls" characters, but I think it can help.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is by `!<whatever-command>`. For example to execute the `ls` that you performed last, you can do a `!ls`. Take a look at the following log to see if this is what you need:

```
nits@nits-excalibur:~$ ls /mnt/Storage_1/Music/
Music I  Music II  Music III  Music IV  Music V  Music_VI
nits@nits-excalibur:~$ cd Documents/
nits@nits-excalibur:~/Documents$ top
nits@nits-excalibur:~/Documents$ !ls
ls /mnt/Storage_1/Music/
Music I  Music II  Music III  Music IV  Music V  Music_VI
```

Comment: This runs the command without displaying it, is there an alternative that displays it as the OP requested?

Comment: In zsh, you can `setopt HIST_VERIFY` and the command will be put in your input buffer, where you can either press enter to accept it, or edit it.

Answer (score 1):

The history is located ~/.bash_history 
Also, for a neat trick to search your bash history press ctrl+r then type the start of the command you're looking for.

and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=204382 for Handy command-line aliases and tricks