# How can I make the LXTerminal accept the arrow key for history search?

Tags: command-line, search, lxde, history, lxterminal

In the bash, one can enable a "search-as-you-type-like" behaviour by changing eg. the .inputrc :

```
  1 ## arrow up
  2 "\e[A":history-search-backward
  3 ## arrow down
  4 #"\e[B":history-search-forward
```

Is there anything similar in the LXTerminal, besides hitting CTRL+r?

Comment: there's another way to do history search with the terminal, it's not the same but it's close enought take a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/108163/selective-command-history-in-the-terminal

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!